# perl: print only function definition name

Tags: perl

I have a file FILE1 with function names.

FILE1 (few more functions name too):

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain
```

FILE2 contains:

```
pChain = ChainCtrlBuildChain(pChainCtrl, pChainCtrl->ChainTable[i].col[j], pDefs);
...
if (eRetVal != kNoError)
            {
                ModTrace((ModT*) pChainCtrl, "ChainCtrlBuildChain: ERROR, chain init failure [chain: %4.4s inst: %d] [err: %d]\n",
...
VideoChainT* ChainCtrlBuildChain(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, char* pChainName, ChainDefT* pDef)
            {
               ...
            }
```

I want to show only function definitions and exclude function declarations.

OUTPUT REQUIRED

```
VideoChainT* ChainCtrlBuildChain(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, char* pChainName, ChainDefT* pDef)
```

CODE

```
#search for function in the file
use strict;
use warnings;

my $function_file = 'functions.txt';
my $src_file = 'ChainController.c';

open(my $ff,'<',$function_file) or die "Cant open $function_file: $!\n";
open(my $sf,'<',$src_file) or die "Cant open $src_file: $!\n";

my @array = <$ff>;
my @array2 = <$sf>;

close($ff);
close($sf);

foreach my $func (@array){
chomp $func;
foreach my $src_line (@array2){
    if ($src_line =~ /$func\(/){
        print $src_line;   
    }
  }
}
```

Although it checks for `(` after function name but it shows both function declaration and function definition.

any idea on how to chck for `;` on the same line as function name as only function declaration has `;` in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "there is no ; till the end of the line":

```
/$func\([^;]+$/
```

Note that this might still not work. The only way how to make it work for 100% is to use a parser.

Comment: yes you are right.i will try to use parser.but this also works for my test case.Thanks